# in wordpress customizing the index css file

Tags: php, wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vKWY.png)

I understand how to edit the style.css (first box i boxed)
I don't know how to edit the (index):321
please suggest me some solution

Comment: please view the image

Comment: Basically , index:321 , stands for on page style. It means that there is a injected css code inside your page's head tag , it obvious that theme is putting some code on there to render the elements according to your theme settings. you can override that properties by using `!important;` or you better go into theme settings , and change there the settings of color or anything you want to change

Comment: thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Index.php means that your internet browser found that piece of CSS code in index.php file. However, it mustn't be necessary physical index.php file because WordPress uses templates and usually builds page by merging/combining different files.
In the image that you provided I saw nav items, if you can't find this code in index.php file - probably you can find it at header.php file.
Of course both index.php and header.php files are editable just like style.css
Please remember that editing template files isn't very good practice - you may lost your changes when you will upgrade template.